# React: How to make an accessible menu?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, accessibility

Here's my codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/accessible-menu-ejzte

I have a menu that pops up when you click on a button. It's functional, but I am noticing that it's different from examples I find online.

`Menu.tsx` is just a `ul` with children:

```
    <Container
      role="menu"
      id={id}
      ref={menu_ref}
      is_visible={open}
      onKeyDown={handleKeyPress}
      onClick={(e: React.MouseEvent) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        onClose();
      }}
      {...rest}
    >
      {children}
    </Container>
```

`MenuItem.tsx` is an `li` with buttons in it:

```
const MenuItem = ({ start_text, onClick }: MenuItemProps) => (
  <Container role="none">
    <ClickableWrapper
      onClick={(e: React.MouseEvent) => onClick && onClick(e)}
      role="menuitem"
    >
      <TextContainer>
        {start_text && <StartText>{start_text}</StartText>}
      </TextContainer>
    </ClickableWrapper>
  </Container>
);
```

However, when I look at other websites, their menus behave differently from mine:

1. https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/menu-button/menu-button-links.html
2. https://mui.com/components/menus/

I noticed these differences:

1. The 1st menu item is automatically focused on when you open the menu by tabbing to the button and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. If the menu is open and you press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, the menu closes and the button is focused

Does this functionality come from Javascript? Or is it default behavior for menus that are built correctly?

I thought accessible elements were all achievable through native HTML, but so far I can't find any differences between my HTML markup and the 2 examples above, so this makes me think that this can only be achieved through JS.